# Grant permissions to a set of databases matching a pattern in MysQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-grant

I'm lead to understand that the following grants all proveleges to all databases that name begin with 'xian_', but mysql complains about a syntax error `near ''xian_`...

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'xian_%.*' TO xian@'192.168.1.%';`

What is the correct syntax?
Am I right in thinking that the `_` needs escaping to `\_` too as it is also a wildcard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `` ` `` instead of `'` in the database name, and escape the `_`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xian\_%`.* TO xian@'192.168.1.%';
```

Comment: Not works on my Mysql Workbench old version 6.3.8, mysql-cli client v5.7.35, server 8.0.2 :( "ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected" or "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table  doesn't exist"